# Connecting to a SQL database using a UDL

Tags: windows-7, mariadb

I am attempting to connect to a remote SQL server (MariaDB running on a Linux machine) on port 3308 using a UDL / data link file, since that is what another program I am using requires. However, I cannot seem to find the right combination of settings to get that to work. Under "Provider" I have tried both "OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers" and "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" and a variety of settings with no luck.

[image: UDL options]

In trying a variety of settings I always receive an "Invalid Connection" error message.

[image: Error message I get]

I can connect to the server and view data with no problem using other programs such as Database Workbench. Though I do not have write access, I think it shouldn't be needed.

Does anyone have some insight on what I can try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you are attempting to set up a linked server from a SQL Server instance to MariaDB?

Comment: Not quite, I don’t have SQL Server installed on my local machine and didn’t think I needed it. Basically, I have a database on this remote server and need to be able to access it from another program (Altium). Altium takes a UDL file as its “connection settings” to do this: I just can’t get the UDL file to connect to the remote server. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, so you probably need to select `MySQL OLEDB Provider` or similar as the provider.

Comment: That was it, I just didn't know where to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doug Dedan got it right, I needed a connector. Here are the steps I took for anyone looking for the solution:

1. Install a connector, [found here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-odbc/)
2. Run the "Data Sources (ODBC)" program
3. Under the "User Data Sources" tab click "Add"
4. Select MariaDB ODBC Driver and click finish
5. Enter a name in the window that pops up then click next. Fill out Server address, port, username and password then click next until the dialog closes.
6. Open your UDL file, choose "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers" as the provider, and select your data source (named at the beginning of step 5). Leave the user name and password field BLANK (but do not check Blank Password)
7. Test the connection - everything should work!